# data from API is not getting updated in Store (Reducer) in React-Redux Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, react-redux

I am trying to get updated data via "service.js" in my reducer "someReducer.js". Though API returned is proper, but the data is not updating in my "Store" it seems (via reducer). Is there any issue in this code? I am not very accostomed to Promises or async-await so please help if you find something wrong in this code!

**service.js**

```
const global = {

  getActressList: async function(){
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:2000/api/actressList");
    console.log('#######', response);
    return response;
  }

}

export default global;
```

**someReducer.js**

```
case "GET_LIST": {
  let data = global.getActressList();
  console.log('*****', data);
  return {
    ...state,
    data: data
  }
}
```

API-Response:

[image]

Response-Structure:

[image]

Comment: For starters, if you're using the standard `fetch` library, your `response` variable will be set to a `Response` object. You'll need to parse the body by adding `const json = await response.json();` after the fetch call – that's where your data will live. It's also likely there is not enough code to show what's going on. What about the rest of the reducer? What about the component?

Comment: You should not set state to a promise, try using [thunk actions](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) instead